# Как доставляется электронная почта?

Tags: unix, sendmail, imap, pop3

Я вот не совсем понимаю, как идет доставка сообщений на почтовый сервер? Мы пишем письмо с user@gmail.com на test@mail.ru. Что происходит на уровне системы? sendmail (или другой мейл агент) доставляет письмо на указанный сервер (mail.ru) или на другой (который прописан в mx-записи)? И самое главное - какому сервису он передается? sendmail-sendmail? Pop3 и imap служат только для того чтобы отдавать почту пользователю? В общем сильно не пинайте, а объясните концепцию или линк на толковую статью. Спасибо.

Comment: Если в вашем вопросе заменить знаки вопрос на восклицательные знаки - то получится ответ :) только предложение про mail.ru переписать в виде "MTA агент (sendmail) доставляет письмо MTA агенту сервера, указанного в MX записи домена адресата сообщения"

Comment: То есть в теории: в mx записи mail.ru, допустим есть in.mail.ru. Получается сервер sendmail gmail.com (ну или какой там мта) соединяется с in.mail.ru по 25 порту и отдает ему данные? Или как собственно процесс передачи происходит?

Comment: Да, именно так, выбирается наиболее приоритетная MX и на ее 25 порт шлется письмо. Если ошибка - выбирается менее приоритетный MX.

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо!

Comment: начать изучение темы можно, например, со [статьи в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80). а дальше — по ссылкам.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предположим, мы написали письмо со своего ящика `user@gmail.com` для `test@mail.ru`. Из веб-формы письмо передаётся MTA (Mail Transfer Agent - почтовый агент) Google, который начинает его обработку. MTA может быть любым - sendmail, postfix, MS Exchange и т.п., порядок действий везде одинаковый.

Вначале MTA выделяет из адреса отправителя имя домена (в нашем случае - `mail.ru`) и посылает DNS-запрос "какие MX-записи у этого домена?". Дело в том, что для почты есть свои собственные записи в DNS, так называемые MX-записи (MX - Mail Exchanger), в которых находятся имена (не *IP-адреса*, а именно *имена* почтовых серверов домена!). В ответ DNS присылает список имён почтовых  серверов. MTA берёт один из полученных имён и посылает DNS-запрос "какой IP у этого имени?". DNS-сервер присылает в ответ адрес (возможно, не один) для имени, после чего MTA соединяется с этим адресом и по стандарному протоколу SMTP (или ESMTP) передаёт письмо почтовому серверу получателя. Сервер получателя кладёт письмо в своё внутреннее хранилище писем для `test@mail.ru` и ждёт пока пользователь подключится и прочитает свою почту.

Пользователь может не использовать web-интерфейс, а подключаться к MTA при помощи отдельной программы - почтового клиента (Mozilla Thunderbird, The Bat и т.п.). Но всё дело в том, что протокол SMTP для этого не подходит, он создан для обмена данными между серверами. Здесь работают два других протокола - *POP3* и *IMAP*. Для клиента разница между ними почти отсутствует, но внутренне они абсолютно непохожи. *IMAP* более современный и умный, *POP3* более старый и поглупее. (Если есть возможность - выставляйте IMAP.) Эти протоколы ответственны за передачу почты между клиентской программой и MTA. Если SMTP однонаправленный (только отправка), то клиентские протоколы двунаправленные (отправка и получение).

Есть ещё одна интересная деталь. MX-записей у домена может быть несколько. То есть у домена может быть несколько почтовых серверов. Казалось бы зачем это надо? Ведь у любого DNS-имени может быть несколько IP-адресов (A-записей), так зачем же усложнять картину? А затем, что у MX-записей есть то, чего нет у A-записей - *приоритет*. Все IP для одного имени равноприоритетны, но для MX-записей можно указывать их "вес". "Вес" - это неотрицательное целое число и чем оно меньше, тем выше приоритет этой записи. MTA всегда вначале пытается соединиться с сервером, имеющим более высокий приоритет и только если ему это не удалось, переходит к серверу с более низким приоритетом.

Comment: Спасибо, весьма доходчиво!